# Access Json-Object that is not stored inside a variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a Wordpress Plugin that stores Json-data in the `<head>` of the HTML Document. It is however not stored inside a variable. Is it still possible for me to access this data? How would I e.g. get the name "XY" in the following example? Thanks a lot for a hint.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    [{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Event","name":"XY"}]
</script>
```

Comment: Can I know what is the user case?